# Problem when request with axios to api go lang. Error decode NOSQL

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, go, axios, nosql

i have this issue, when i try to post with axios in my front-ent to my back-end in go lang showed this:

timed out while checking out a connection from connection pool: context canceled; maxPoolSize: 100, connections in use by cursors: 0, connections in use by transactions: 0, connections in use by other operations: 1

I did print for see if the information was  correct and is all right.
The error ocorres when Try to Decode the information of  my result of MongoDB in go lang.
But this only happened when I do it with front.
If I call directly like with postman... I don't have problem.

My service that calls mongoDB.

```
func (p *profile)CheckInformationValid(ctx echo.Context,email string, password string, profile *models.Profile)  (string, error) {

    filter := map[string]interface{}{"Email": email, "PassWord": password}
    result := storage.GetInstance().FindOne(ctx, "profile",filter)

    fmt.Println(result)
    if result == nil {
        return  "", errors.New("Check Information: user not find")
    }

    err := result.Decode(profile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return "",errors.New("Error Decode Profile") 
    }

    fmt.Println(profile)

    log.Infof("[CheckInformationValid] Object : %s \n", profile, "")

    return profile.UserId , nil
}
```

the erros ocorrer in result.Decode.

my front:

```
export async function validLogin(email, password) { 

  const data = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
  let headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  };

  return await axios.post('http://localhost:1323/profile/valid', data, headers)
}
```

Comment: For someone that has these problem, it is because the context, I use the echo.context and for some reason gave these error. if you change your logic to context.Context it works. just in the begining when you configure your route, pass the context of echo (if you are use the echo)and in your handler when you gonna pass the context for service pass the context.Background. and configure the rest to context.Context